# Different local database configuration Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I'm working in a team in a Rails project.

Each of us have a local database for development purpose. We have a problem: Everyone have different configuration for the local database. When someone make a commit without reset the `/config/database.yml` the other members of the team can't use their database because the access is not configured.

Can I have a local configuration not commited? To each one can works without problem and without the need of re-set the file every time? Sometime like the `local_settings.py` in Django

Comment: Is ignore in your VCS not good for you?

Comment: I have more configuration there (like the qa, staging configuration). So I need the shared information. I don't know if we can have a local configuration with just development purpose.

Comment: You can do it with Environmental variables I think.

Comment: You could normalize database setups across developers. It's good to have a similar setup anyways.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can [configure the database in Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-a-database) via both the `config/database.yml` file and the `DATABASE_URL` env var. They are merged but settings from `DATABASE_URL` take precedence.

A good solution is to check in the `config/database.yml` with a basic configuration thats just enough to support `postgres.app` or whatever is the most common solution.

Developers that need other settings can set the `DATABASE_URL` env var to customize the database configuration. Gems like [figaro](https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro) and [dotenv](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv) make this easier.

If you have ever wondered this how Heroku manages to use the correct DB no matter what you throw into `database.yml` and the `DATABASE_URL` ENV var is how you should be configuring your production DB.

**Why should I use ENV vars and not more database_*.yaml files?**

> The twelve-factor app stores config in environment variables (often
>   shortened to env vars or env). Env vars are easy to change between
>   deploys without changing any code; unlike config files, there is
>   little chance of them being checked into the code repo accidentally;
>   and unlike custom config files, or other config mechanisms such as
>   Java System Properties, they are a language- and OS-agnostic standard.
>   https://12factor.net/config

Comment: It was an excellent answer. I really thanks. I say nothing but accepted before. I take this time to say thanks. And tell you we took the idea of the DATABASE_URL. We are using it.

Comment: In 2021 you can consider using the Rails encrypted secrets which offer some security benifits over env vars.

Answer (score 2):

Add `config/database.yml` in to the `.gitignore` file at root path of your rails-app.
Copy `config/database.yml` with the values you need for production into `config/database_example.yml`.
Now you can modify your local database and in production you copy `config/database_expample.yml` to `config/database.yml`

If the config file is ignored by git, everyone can change it locally without getting tracked by git.

EDIT:
HERE YOU SEE HOW YOU CAN REMOVE FILE FROM TRACKING!!!
[Ignore files that have already been committed to a Git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139762/ignore-files-that-have-already-been-committed-to-a-git-repository)

Comment: this works only if you haven't already commited config/database.yml. Git ignore doesn't ignore committed files. In our system we don't even have database.yml checked in. We have various database.production.yml and so on, each having placeholders in them. At deploy time the correct version is found and the placeholders replaced with real data (so that that data is nowhere checked into our repo). THEN you can add your local version of database.yml to .gitignore and it works fine.

Comment: Still seems like a very un-convention over configuration approach and a very hacky solution to a problem which ENV vars handle better.

Comment: I agree, ENV vars are always better. But in this example I showed how to use gitignore not to change current workflow.

Comment: I've seen this system setup at a few jobs now. I probably wouldn't choose to use it, but it's not a hacky, one-off solution by any means.  Oh and the edit you added to show how to ignore committed files completes your answer nicely so +1